# Serializing array/object of nested objects comming from Entity in Symfony

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I need to return Json from specific Entity in this way:
[image]

By now I reached t result:

[image]

With he following code:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\LogStatus;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

class LogController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/logs/statuses", name="log_statuses", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function index(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {

        $request = new Request($_POST);
        $data = $request->getContent();
        $data = json_decode($data);
        $data = (array)$data;

        $deviceId = $data['filter'];

        $logStatuses = $entityManager->getRepository(LogStatus::class)
            ->findBy(['deviceid' => $deviceId], ['createdat' => 'DESC']);

        return new JsonResponse([
                'rows' => (array)$logStatuses[0]
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

**Question:** how should `$logStatuses` be coded to get expected Json format (or manipulated in extend) without iterating through each object.

Comment: What's your result if you just `return $this->json(['rows' => [$logStatuses]]);`? You might need to install `symfony/serializer`.

Comment: @msg your suggestion is right $this->json makes my day! Thanks!

Comment: If you need finer control over the response, I'd suggest to take a look to the `->json()` source code and the [serializer docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html). You could also use it in place of the `json_decode` call.